# Bug Tracker Architecture

Tags: ddd-repositories

I am creating a Bug Tracker application (toy one) with DDD in mind. I have a BugRepository with methods like Add / Delete / Save and a user Repository having the same kind of methods (Actually both derive from IRepository). Now Bug has a Property called "Assigned To" which is a column in DB where the ID of the user is stored.

Now I need a method called "FindAssignee" or rather I want to know who the bug is assigned to. Where do i put that?

I was thinking that I could say --> In BugRepository add a method called "FindAssignee". But that would return a "USER" object. Is that OK? Aren't repositories for an aggregate root (Bug this case) supposed to return ONLY their entities (Bug again) ?

Comment: I'm assuming DDD stands for domain-driven design. Clueless people like me appreciate having things spelled out ;)

Comment: @phihag - Mea Culpa. Will spell out in future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that OK?

Yes.

> Aren't repositories for an aggregate root (Bug this case) supposed to return ONLY their entities (Bug again) ?

Yes.

But your query isn't to a aggregate root.

Your query is against a specific Bug which has one or more Assignees.

Comment: @S.Lott -Thanks for the reply. In my case User is also an aggregate root. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @user554833: Not at all.  Objects are "related" to each other, otherwise the world collapses into disconnected islands of irrelevant gibberish.

Comment: @S.Lott - Thanks for follow-up. I asked that specifically because - you mentioned - "But your query isn't to a aggregate root". Was there a particular reason for that comment? I would like to get to the depths of that comment for my knowledge!

Comment: @user554833: First, find a bug -- a query to an aggregate root.  Given a specific instance of Bug (not some aggregate root) you want the associated User(s).  This is a simple relationship between objects, nothing more.  It can **also** be viewed as a painful search through the User aggregate root for some kind of complex match.  But it isn't.  It's just a relationship between objects.  Bug to User.  Nothing more.

Comment: @S.Lott - Thank you. Would you then view this relationship the same as "Order Line Item" to "Order" where Order line item cannot live without order but here User / Bug can live on its own. Both are being exposed the same way as props for example. Sorry if its a dumb question. Learner this side.

Comment: @user554833: I don't understand the question.  "same ... where Order line item cannot live without order" and "but here User / Bug can live on its own" are opposites.  Clearly, there's a different and -- just as clearly -- you've articulated the difference.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: @S.Lott- Sorry, If my question was not clear. What i wanted to know was - An order line item is NOT an aggregate root but a User is. In our discussion, a repository (Bug - Aggregate) sending out User (aggregate root) VS an OrderRepository (Order aggregate) sending Line Item (NOT aggregate). Dont we need to differentiate this kind of exposing of entities through repositories ?

Comment: @user554833: "Dont we need to differentiate this kind of exposing of entities through repositories ?"  No.  The persistence of the objects (OrderLineItem vs. User) reflects one kind of dependency (Composition vs. Aggregation).  But the essential fact of an association is a "superclass" of those two more specific kinds of associations.